# How do you retrieve a publication list from exact target using the soap api?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I can retrieve a data extension from exact traget using something like this:

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();

using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>(ExactTargetToken);
    var untyped = header.GetUntypedHeader("fueloauth ", "http://exacttarget.com");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);

    RetrieveRequest req = new RetrieveRequest();

    req.Properties = new string[] { "TheKeyIUse", "Email" };
    req.ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[TheDataExtensionName]";
    req.Filter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "TheKeyIUse", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new[] { "someValue" } };
    string msg;
    APIObject[] apiObj;

    client.Retrieve(req, out msg, out apiObj);
}
```

Now I need to receive the content of a "publication list". Is that possible through the Soap Api?

**Edit:**
The request that gets the PublicationList is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>

        <fueloauth  xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">mykey</fueloauth >
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:985300a9-409b-45e7-ad8f-b756bd10de9c</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>

    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>List</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ListName</Properties>
                <Properties>ListClassification</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Object for a Publication List is simply a `List`, with a `ListClassification` property value of `PublicationList`.

Object details: [List](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/list/)

Some code samples: [Retrieving a List from an Account](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_a_list_from_an_account/)

Here's the C# snippet from the page:

```
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
rr.ObjectType = "List";

SimpleFilterPart sf = new SimpleFilterPart();
sf.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
sf.Property = "ListName";
sf.Value = new String[] { listName };

rr.Filter = sf;

rr.Properties = new string[] { "ID", "ListName", "ListClassification" };

status = framework.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out result);

List l = (List)result[0];
```

Comment: This worked. It resulted in a request like i added to the question. I actually need to rceive the subscribers insde of a publicationList. I create a new question for that.